# Compact surface

Tags: differential-geometry, compactness, surfaces

To check if the surface $x^2-y^2+z^4=1$ is compact, we have to check if the surface is closed and bounded.

Could you give me some hints how exactly we check that?

How can we check if it closed and how if it is bounded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not bounded. Fix $z=1$, then you have a subset of the surface defined by $x^2-y^2 = 0$, so both $x$ and $y$ can go off to $\infty$ without any constraint (besides being equal up to sign).

So the surface is not compact. To check nonetheless whether it's closed look at a sequence of points satisfying the equation and assume the sequence converges. If the limit also satisfies the equation then the surface is closed (this is true, since you are dealing with continuous functions).

Comment: I see... When we have the surface $x^2+y^2+z^4=1$ we do the following: $$$$ We consider the sequence $(x_n, y_n, z_n)$ such that $(x_n, y_n, z_n) \rightarrow (x,y,z)$ and $x^2+y^2+z^4=1$. $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (x_n^2+y_n^2+z_n^4)=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}x_n^2+\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}y_n^2+\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}z_n^4=(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}x_n)^2+(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}y_n)^2+(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}z_n)^4 \\ =x^2+y^2+z^4=1$$ 
So the surface is closed.

Comment: So that the equality $x^2+y^2+z^4=1$ holds it must stand that $$0 \leq x^2 \leq 1, \ 0\leq y \leq 1, \ 0 \leq z^4\leq 1$$ so $$-1\leq x\leq 1, \ -1\leq y \leq 1 , \ -1\leq z\leq 1 \ .$$ 

So, the surface is bounded. 
$$$$ 
Therefore, the surface is compact. 
$$$$ 
Is everything correct?

Comment: For closed: not quite. You need to assume $x_n^2 + y_n^2 + z_n^4= 1$ and $(x_n,y_n,z_n) \rightarrow (x,y,z)$. If you can then conclude that $x^2+y^2+z^4 =1$ (which is trivial since $x\mapsto x^2$ and $x\mapsto x^4$ are continuous) then the surface is closed. For bounded: yes, when you have a plus sign everywhere, then you can easily bound everything by $1$.

Comment: For closed: Do you mean it as follows? $$$$ We consider the sequence $(x_n,y_n,z_n)$ such that $(x_n,y_n,z_n)\rightarrow (x,y,z)$ and $x_n^2+y_n^2+z_n^4=1$. $$1=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (x_n^2+y_n^2+z_n^4)=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}x_n^2+\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}y_n^2+\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}z_n^4=(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}x_n)^2+(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}y_n)^2+(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}z_n)^4 \\ =x^2+y^2+z^4$$ Since $x^2+y^2+z^4=1$ we conclude that the surface is closed.

Comment: @MaryStar yep, that will do. You could, alternatively, take the approach from kccu's answer and conclude that the preimage of the closed set $\{ 1\}$ under the continuous map $(x, y, z)\mapsto x^2 + y^2 + z^4$ is closed. It's good to know both (or even more ;-) approaches. In this case both are rather easy to follow, this is often not true.

Comment: I understand!! Thanks a lot for your help!! :-) $$$$ I also have to sketch this compact surface. Could you give me a hint how we could do that?

Comment: @MaryStar what do you mean by 'sketch'? Draw a picture?

Comment: I think so. How do we know what kind of surface it is?

Comment: @MaryStar Since the surface is obviously symmetric with respect to reflections through the $x, y,$ and $z$ plane it would make sense to draw only one half of the surface and write that as a graph. E.g. $z= (1-x^2+y^2)^{\frac{1}{4}}$, and, since it will look slightly different, $y=  \sqrt{(1-x^2 + z^4)}$

Comment: So to draw the surface we have to draw the parts $y=\sqrt{1-x^2-z^4}$ and $y=-\sqrt{1-x^2-z^4}$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar yes. I got the signs wrong, but you figured out the correct ones.

Comment: Are the graphs of these two parts known? How can we figure that out?

Comment: @MaryStar You will need to calculate some sample values (or observe that by fixing, e.g. $x$ the resulting graph of a function in one variable is well known). You may also try to fix one value for $x, y$ or $z$ for the original equation and try to draw the resulting plane curve, which will be a circle for fixed $z$ or a curve looking a bit like an ellipse in case $x$ or $y$ is fixed. That way you can try to draw several curves on the surface and get a complete picture by drawing enough of them. If you have a computer program which can do that that may save you time.

Comment: @MaryStar After you asking repeatedly for extended support (and, as it seems, with success) I'd appreciate if you could accept my answer.

Comment: Ok... Thanks a lot!! :-)

Answer (score 5):

As the first answer indicates, this set is not bounded.

To determine whether the surface is closed, instead of thinking about convergent sequences of points on the surface, think about the function defining the surface. Let $f(x,y,z)=x^2-y^2+z^4$ and notice that the surface is the set $f^{-1}(\{1\})$, i.e. the set $\{(x,y,z)~:~x^2-y^2+z^4=1\}$. Since $f$ is a continuous function and $\{1\}$ is a closed set, $f^{-1}(\{1\})$ is closed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this will not be bounded. Note that $z=1$ will always satisfy $z^4 = 1$ so $x^2 - y^2 = 0$ will suffice, i.e. just take $x = y$ and now you have infinitely many solutions as arbitrarily large as you wish.

The points on this surface are 
$$\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbf{R}^3 \mid f(x,y,z) = x^2 - y^2 + z^4 - 1 = 0\} = f^{-1} (0)$$.

Now it is clear that it is closed since it is the inverse image of a closed set under a continuous map. I want to emphasize this technique which can be generalized much further, such as to show any zero set of a continuous function is closed. These types of problems frequently appear on examinations and qualifiers (e.g. Berkeley).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!! :-)